# Append a span to a specific span on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code as it appears now:

```
<p class="intro" id="186949"><span class="namepart"><span class="name">john cena</span></span>
```

Code as I want it to appear:

```
<p class="intro" id="186949"><span class="namepart"><span class="name">john cena</span><span class="special">name2</span></span>
```

I'd like to append another span to the end of "john cena" Using Jquery, but only to that specific post, with the ID "186949"

I know I have to use append, but I don't know how to ensure that the span goes only in that post, and after the name span.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('#186949 .namepart .name').after($('<span/>', {class : 'special', text : 'name2'}))
```

Comment: Oh absolutely fantastic! Thank you :)
Let's say I wanted to append it all posts with the name "john cena"
Would that then be

$(".name:contains('john cena')").after($('<span/>', {class : 'special', text : 'name2'}))

Comment: Yes but "john cena" will be case sensitive. If you need it to be case insensistive or select more than 1 text, i got a plugin for you, just tell me.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, +1 for being faster than me :)

Answer (score 1):

Check here [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YPKwf/)

```
var content = '<span class="special">name2</span>';
$(content).insertAfter('#186949 .name');
```